# Segmentation fault on running created app into android from eclipse

Tags: android

I am getting
    "ActivityManager: Segmentation fault"
while running one sample project from eclipse into my android device.

One month before when my android version was JB 4.1 there were no issues.

My phone is galaxy nexus
android version = JB 4.2.1
Rooted
drivers installed from Samsung site.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by trial and error method..

```
  Make sure your sdk and adt are of latest version.  
  If the issue still there then its due to the rom installed.   

    1. Some custom roms may leads to this issue.   
    2. Installation of busybox may lead to this issue.
    3. Corrupted OS installation.
```

**This can be solved by wiping all data and putting stock rom back.**